# Why our server with centOS i686 showing 14 GB usable RAM

Tags: memory, operating-systems, 32-bit, paging

We have CentOS server 6 i686 (installed by previous employee) on blade server which is having 32GB RAM (4GB x 8 slots).
**The usable RAM is 14GB.**

My question is why it is showing 14GB instead of 4GB, which is maximum for 32-bit OS.
Can I remove RAM in 4 slots to have total 16GB RAM, then what will be the usable RAM?

Comment: Most (all?) 32-bit Linuxes can access more than 4GB of ram, with PAE. Are you 100% positive that every ram stick is 4GB? Or that the computer can use all 8 slots together?

Comment: @EdGrimm It is true that 32-bit x86 processors are not limited to 4 GB, but "bank switching" is not how it's done. The mechanism is called PAE. It is simply a slight modification of the  already-existing page table mechanism. 32-bit Windows Server systems can take advantage of this. 32-bit Windows non-Server SKUs ("client" versions) cannot, but this is only because the OS deliberately limits itself to 4 GB RAM - they can still run with PAE enabled. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension

Comment: @EdGrimm Also: the MMU is part of the CPU chip, not on the motherboard.

Comment: After reading your link... other than terminology changes, reducing the size of the banks down to 4K, and moving it onto the CPU, that still reads like bank switching to me. Admittedly, this is an industry that gets very particular about terminology, and doesn't like to admit general terms still apply even though the chip makers have pushed a new term to honor having moved the process onto the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

> instead of 4GB, which is maximum for 32-bit OS.

Programs on Linux (and most operating systems) don't deal with physical memory directly – they work with virtual addresses which are translated by the hardware according to a mapping that the OS configures.

So although 32-bit systems use 32-bit *pointers* and a program cannot see more than 4 GB of *virtual memory* at once, the page tables (virtual-to-physical memory mappings) can actually represent longer physical addresses than that. The corresponding x86 feature is called [Physical Address Extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/physical-address-extension) ([also](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/physical-address-extension)) and allows these mappings to resolve to 36-bit physical addresses.

This means that you could simultaneously have multiple processes mapped to different virtual 4 GB areas in the physical up-to-64 GB space. (The same happens if you run 32-bit processes on a 64-bit OS.)

---

Similarly, 16-bit systems could use more than 64 kB of physical memory through tricks such as segmentation (which on 8086 allowed effectively 20-bit physical addresses) or bank switching (which allowed remapping the same memory addresses to different physical areas, e.g. C64 or MS-DOS XMS/EMS).